# How to insert/delete node at a specific position in given json file using PHP

Tags: php, json

I need to add a new node to a deep nested json file. I cant figure out how to get the array index to which the node is to be inserted.

This is for accessing and managing collaterals in JSON file.I have tried to use `array_split()` function but the third parameter only adds node with one value.

Sample JSON File:

```
{
   "IsNew":"0",
   "Title":"Industry",
   "View":"grid",
   "File":"",
   "Items":[
      {
         "IsNew":"0",
         "Title":"Industrial Products",
         "Image":"Industrial-Products.png",
         "View":"list",
         "Items":[
            {
               "IsNew":"0",
               "Title":"Offerings",
               "View":"detaillist",
               "Items":[

               ]
            },
            {
               "IsNew":"0",
               "Title":"Collateral",
               "View":"multidetaillist",
               "Items":[
                  {
                     "IsNew":"0",
                     "Title":"Flyers and Brochures",
                     "Subtitle":"",
                     "Items":[
                        {
                           "IsNew":"0",
                           "Title":"Building Solutions",
                           "View":"pdf",
                           "File":"Building_Solutions.pdf",
                           "Type":"1"
                        },
                        {
                           "IsNew":"0",
                           "Title":"Industrial Machinery",
                           "View":"pdf",
                           "File":"Industrial_Machinery.pdf",
                           "Type":"1"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Node To Add in Flyers and Brochures items:

```
 {
      "IsNew": "0",
      "Title": "abc",
      "Image": "abc",
      "View": "pdf",
      "File": "abc",
      "Type": "1"
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: Your original sample JSON file is not valid. It is missing some closing parenthesis which I've taken the liberty of fixing in the code below.

The php code for appending your item is:

```
$jsonStr = '{
    "IsNew": "0",
  "Title": "Industry",
  "View": "grid",
  "File": "",
  "Items": [
    {
        "IsNew": "0",
      "Title": "Industrial Products",
      "Image": "Industrial-Products.png",
      "View": "list",
      "Items": [
    {
        "IsNew": "0",
          "Title": "Offerings",
          "View": "detaillist",
          "Items": []
        }
        ,
     {
         "IsNew": "0",
          "Title": "Collateral",
          "View": "multidetaillist",
          "Items": [
          {
              "IsNew": "0",
              "Title": "Flyers and Brochures",
              "Subtitle": "",
              "Items": [
                 {
                     "IsNew": "0",
                  "Title": "Building Solutions",
                  "View": "pdf",
                  "File": "Building_Solutions.pdf",
                  "Type": "1"
                },
                {
                    "IsNew": "0",
                  "Title": "Industrial Machinery",
                  "View": "pdf",
                  "File": "Industrial_Machinery.pdf",
                  "Type": "1"
                }
             ]
}]}]}]}';

$insertStr = '{
      "IsNew": "0",
      "Title": "abc",
      "Image": "abc",
      "View": "pdf",
      "File": "abc",
      "Type": "1"
 }';

// turns json strings into objects
$obj = json_decode($jsonStr);
$insertObj = json_decode($insertStr);


// target the node is $obj->Items[0]->Items[1]->Items[0]->Items
// so we just append the object to the node
$obj->Items[0]->Items[1]->Items[0]->Items[] = $insertObj;

$newJson = json_encode($obj);
echo($newJson);
```

This will result in:

```
    {
       "IsNew":"0",
       "Title":"Industry",
       "View":"grid",
       "File":"",
       "Items":[
          {
         "IsNew":"0",
         "Title":"Industrial Products",
         "Image":"Industrial-Products.png",
         "View":"list",
         "Items":[
            {
               "IsNew":"0",
               "Title":"Offerings",
               "View":"detaillist",
               "Items":[

               ]
            },
            {
               "IsNew":"0",
               "Title":"Collateral",
               "View":"multidetaillist",
               "Items":[
                  {
                     "IsNew":"0",
                     "Title":"Flyers and Brochures",
                     "Subtitle":"",
                     "Items":[
                        {
                           "IsNew":"0",
                           "Title":"Building Solutions",
                           "View":"pdf",
                           "File":"Building_Solutions.pdf",
                           "Type":"1"
                        },
                        {
                           "IsNew":"0",
                           "Title":"Industrial Machinery",
                           "View":"pdf",
                           "File":"Industrial_Machinery.pdf",
                           "Type":"1"
                        },
                        {
                           "IsNew":"0",
                           "Title":"abc",
                           "Image":"abc",
                           "View":"pdf",
                           "File":"abc",
                           "Type":"1"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this json...

```
{
 "IsNew": "0",
 "Title": "Industry",
 "View": "grid",
 "File": "",
 "Items": [
 {
    "IsNew": "0",
    "Title": "Industrial Products",
    "Image": "Industrial-Products.png",
    "View": "list",
    "Items": [ 
               {
                "IsNew": "0",
                "Title": "Offerings",
                "View": "detaillist",
                "Items": []
               },
               {
               "IsNew": "0",
               "Title": "Collateral",
               "View": "multidetaillist",
               "Items": [
                          {
                           "IsNew": "0",
                           "Title": "Flyers and Brochures",
                           "Subtitle": "",
                           "Items": [

                                    {
                                     "IsNew": "0",
                                      "Title": "Building Solutions",
                                      "View": "pdf",
                                       "File": "Building_Solutions.pdf",
                                       "Type": "1"
                                    },
                                    {
                                     "IsNew": "0",
                                      "Title": "Industrial Machinery",
                                    "View": "pdf",
                                    "File": "Industrial_Machinery.pdf",
                                     "Type": "1"
                                    }, 
                                   {
                                   "IsNew": "0",
                                    "Title": "abc",
                                   "Image": "abc",
                                   "View": "pdf",
                                   "File": "abc",
                                   "Type": "1"
                                 }

           ]
          }
        ]

      }
     ]
    }
  ] 
}
```

Comment: you create new node array and after you add in items object using php

Comment: You  need to explain your answer so someone understands why it works.